# Correct way in Postgresql 9.2 to call a function in a query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I noticed something strange today my log files.  I see a "NOTICE" getting logged over and over again.  And I think I've figured out the cause but don't under stand it or the fix.

The query is:

`select (get_account_details(account.id)).* from account where id in (113126123254, 116261470380);`

get_account_details will log a message in certain situations - one case is when the account has a daily_spend_limit.  In my logs I'm seeing:

```
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 116261470380 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
NOTICE:  Account 113126123254 has a daily_spend_limit of 10.00.  Remaining balance as been calculated as 10.00
```

Baffling, but I finally noticed that it was getting called 17 times where account.  Which is the exact number of columns in account table.

If I run:

`select * from get_account_details(113126123254);`

I only get 1 notice logged.

What's going on here and how do I "correctly" write this query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't why the simpler construct invokes the function once for each column, but this is one way to suppress it:

```
select (get_account_details).* from 
(
    select get_account_details(account.id) from account 
         where id in (113126123254, 116261470380)
) foo
```

Since you can't reproduce that and since I don't have your schema handy, let me create the schema from scratch:

```
create table foo (id integer, a text, b text, c text, d text, e text);
insert into foo (id) select * from generate_series(1,4);
create function get_foo(int) returns setof foo as $$ BEGIN 
    RAISE NOTICE 'dfjkl'; 
    return query select * from foo where id=$1; 
END $$ language plpgsql;
```

Now execute these, the first gives 12 `NOTICE`, the second gives 2.

```
select (get_foo(id)).* from foo where id in (1,2);
select (get_foo).* from (select get_foo(id) from foo where id in (1,2)) ssss;
```

Comment: I just tested your solution and I get the same log output.